# Can't get field from soql query even though it exists

Tags: apex, soql

I'm working with a trailhead org. I've created a custom field on Account(TrailApp_Test57__Country__c).
I have this query and it has no errors but, when trying to get the TrailApp_Test57__Country__c value of the object it displays **"Variable does not exist: TrailApp_Test57_Country__c"**
This is my code:

```
List<SObject> sObjLIST= [SELECT Id, TrailApp_Test57__Country__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :recordId];
String country = sObjLIST[0].TrailApp_Test57__Country__c;
```

And this is the created field:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Complete apex code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static wrapperResponse getDefaultFieldValuesByRecordId(String recordId, String sObjectOrigin){
    wrapperResponse response = new wrapperResponse();
    List<SObject> sObjLIST;
    String sObjectName = Id.valueOf(recordId).getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
    if(sObjectOrigin == 'Opportunity'){
        if(sObjectName == 'Account'){
            sObjLIST = [SELECT Id, TrailApp_Test57__Country__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :recordId];
            response.accountID = recordId;
            response.country = sObjLIST[0].TrailApp_Test57_Country__c;
        }
    }
    return response;
}

public class wrapperResponse{
    @AuraEnabled public String accountID;
    @AuraEnabled public String contactID;
    @AuraEnabled public String country;
}
```

And this is the error I get:

**Variable does not exist: TrailApp_Test57_Country__c** on line 38 which is the one that set response.country.

Comment: The error message leaves me to believe there is more going on like a code formatting error. Please post the entire error message including line number and the corresponding code with surrounding code (by copying not typing to reduce differences). It is not a run time error and not a permissions issue as it is written.

Comment: @Eric sorry for the delay. I just added the apex code and message retrieve. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a field's value from sObject, you will have to use the get method, you cannot get the value of field (other than Id field) using  dot notation. Hence, your code should be

```
String country =(string)sObjLIST[0].get('TrailApp_Test57__Country__c') ;
```

Or simply assign your SOQL result to `List<Account>` instead of `List<sObject>`, and then you can use dot notation to access the mentioned field.

```
String country = sObjLIST[0].TrailApp_Test57__Country__c;
```

More help on [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) link

Comment: Hi, I've written it wrong but even though with that it's still giving me the same error...

Comment: Hi, I have seen that  you have updated the question, but you again added the underscore in the wrong place. It should be `TrailApp_Test57__Country__c` and not `TrailApp__Test57_Country__c` (Note that additional underscore should be after Test57)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. But the point is that in my code both fields are written the same but I can't still manage to retrieve it because it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, updated the answer, this should work fine

Comment: Hi. This is working now. I used String.valueOf(sObjLIST[0].get('TrailApp_Test57__Country__c')) in my code and it's working right. Thanks!

Comment: That's great !!

Answer (score 2):

Check the Field Level Security (FLS) by clicking that middle button in your screenshot.  On the FLS page, make sure the logged in user's profile has the Visible checkbox marked true, and that the Read Only checkbox is left unmarked.